# Spring data Neo4j: do I need a index for each inherited class?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have

```
class A {
String property;
}

class B extends A {
...
}
```

and on my neo4j database I have

```
    Indexes
       ON :A(property) ONLINE for uniqueness constraint
```

When i code:

```
B entityB = neo4jTemplate.loadByProperty(B.class, "property", propertyvalue)
```

will it hit the A index?
or do I need

```
Indexes
     ON :A(property) ONLINE for uniqueness constraint
     ON :B(property) ONLINE for uniqueness constraint
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`neo4jTemplate.loadByProperty(B.class, "property", propertyvalue)` does a `MATCH (n:B) ...` so you will need to define an index on `B` too